# How does APT "find" packages?

Tags: linux, apt

Where does APT look for packages once invoked on some package name? Is there a way of editing its "search" behavior?

Comment: "editing its 'search' behavior" = changing where it looks...I am on the ground level with a lot to this.

Comment: Look in `/etc/apt/`—that's where apt is configured, including where it downloads package lists from (sources.list), which ones it prefers (preferences), etc. The are manual pages (unfortunately not entirely thorough).

Answer (score 3):

On the Linux machine I have access to, `apt edit-sources` will open an editor with the current `sources.list` for editing. When the editor exits, some basic sanity checks are made of the edited list before it replaces the old list.

This is the configuration file that the `apt` uses for fetching packages.

You may well want to have a peek at the manual for `sources.list` before editing it (`man sources.list`).

The file usually lives in `/etc/apt/`.